# Java LWJGL - Gradle just don't want to find artifacts

Tags: java, gradle, build

I'm trying to setup a clone of a repository using IntelliJ IDEA. ([Github-Link](https://github.com/Games-With-Gabe-Community/Azurite))

It uses gradle and it is a project based on LWJGL (a java library for native OpenGL access).

And gradle just doesnt want to build, because it can't find the artifacts, although nobody else working on this project has similar problems.

I'm using this gradle build:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.8.3
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2021-02-22 16:13:28 UTC
Revision:     9e26b4a9ebb910eaa1b8da8ff8575e514bc61c78

Kotlin:       1.4.20
Groovy:       2.5.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
JVM:          1.8.0_152 
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

I searched for weeks now and tried different solutions, that worked for other people, e.g. resetting dependency cache or turning offline-mode on/off

I even manually looked up all links and verified, that all files behind them do exist.

The TLS protocol mentioned in the error message below didn't help at, I tried changing the used protocol version and it just became worse.

Some people mentioned something about proxies, but I literally don't see, why this should be necessary, because Maven (which I usually use) does work with no problems. And Maven can find those very same artifacts with zero problems. Sadly I cannot change the project from gradle to maven.

If there is more information needed, please just ask :)

Gradle tells me:

```
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve org.lwjgl:lwjgl-bom:3.2.3.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve org.lwjgl:lwjgl-bom:3.2.3.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/lwjgl/lwjgl-bom/3.2.3/lwjgl-bom-3.2.3.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/lwjgl/lwjgl-bom/3.2.3/lwjgl-bom-3.2.3.pom'.
               > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/6.8.3/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
                  > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
      > Could not resolve org.lwjgl:lwjgl-bom:3.2.3.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/lwjgl/lwjgl-bom/3.2.3/lwjgl-bom-3.2.3.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/lwjgl/lwjgl-bom/3.2.3/lwjgl-bom-3.2.3.pom'.
               > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/6.8.3/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
                  > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   > Could not find org.lwjgl:lwjgl:.
     Required by:
         project :
   > Could not find org.lwjgl:lwjgl-glfw:.
     Required by:
         project :
   > Could not find org.lwjgl:lwjgl-openal:.
     Required by:
         project :
   > Could not find org.lwjgl:lwjgl-opengl:.
     Required by:
         project :
   > Could not find org.lwjgl:lwjgl-stb:.
     Required by:
         project :
   > Could not resolve org.joml:joml:1.10.1.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve org.joml:joml:1.10.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/joml/joml/1.10.1/joml-1.10.1.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/joml/joml/1.10.1/joml-1.10.1.pom'.
               > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/6.8.3/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
                  > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
      > Could not resolve org.joml:joml:1.10.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/joml/joml/1.10.1/joml-1.10.1.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/joml/joml/1.10.1/joml-1.10.1.pom'.
               > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/6.8.3/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
                  > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```